# NavLink force update active route?

Tags: reactjs

```
              <NavLink
                to={prop.path}
                className="nav-link"
                activeClassName="active"
                forceUpdate
              >
                <i className={prop.icon} />
                <p>{prop.name}</p>
              </NavLink>
```

Ideally I want to do something similar to the above code, when you click on the active NavLink, it would force the component to unmount and remount. Is it possible?

Comment: There is no such prop and force update to an existing route does not have a clean solution, most of them are hacks!

Comment: Check this link: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1982